# java pattern compile regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
String HTML = some HTML source code that contains String a,b

String a = "<a class="cit-dark-link" href="http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=6912391300348162186">88</a>"

String b = "<a class="cit-dark-link" href="http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=18217435431424551679">41</a>"

String ex = ?

Pattern patternObject = Pattern.compile(ex);
Matcher matcherObject = patternObject.matcher(HTML);

while (matcherObject.find()) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Cite is " + matcherObject.group(1));
  }
```

Hi, I am new to JAVA and Regex and I am wondering how can I write the String ex so that it only prints. (I hope I am clear enough)

Cite is 88

Cite is 41

Comment: Use a proper HTML parser to do this: load the input string, find `<a>` tag with the given class, print its node value. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I do it without a HTML parser package?

Comment: How can you do it with an HTML parser? Unwisely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
Pattern patternObject = Pattern.compile("<a class=\"cit-dark-link(.*?)cites=(\\d)+\">(.*?)</a>");
            Matcher matcherObject = patternObject.matcher(HTML);

            while (matcherObject.find()) {
                    System.out.println("DEBUG: Cite is " + matcherObject.group(3));
              }
```

This prints :

```
DEBUG: Cite is 88
DEBUG: Cite is 41
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String ex = ".*>([1-9]+)<.*";
```

If you only want the digits, you can ignore everything else. I don't know how you apply URL to HTML, but this test is for one URL from user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String HTML = in.readLine();
    URL a = new URL (HTML);

    String ex = ".*>([1-9]+)<.*";

    Pattern patternObject = Pattern.compile(ex);
    Matcher matcherObject = patternObject.matcher(a.toString());

    while (matcherObject.find()) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Cite is " + matcherObject.group(1));
      }
}
```

Comment: How do i ignore the 6912391300348162186? Because there can be different string with different digits.

Comment: .*> should ignore everything prior to the group right after the >, I'll update my answer with the test code.